# Comparison of continuous two-dimensional state space grids across participants

Tags: statistical-significance, density-function, kernel-smoothing

Each participant completed *k* trials from which I obtained  *x* and *y* coordinates describing a location on a Cartesian coordinate system (so, each participant has *x$_1$*, *y$_1$*, … *x$_k$*, *y$_k$*  datapoints). I want to statistically test if these coordinates move to another location on the plane as a function of another variable (*z*). All variables are continuous.

So far, I computed 2d binned kernel density estimates for each participant (on a 100 x 100 plane) and estimated the increase/decrease for each of these estimates as a function of the z-score using linear regression (using lmer). See figure one for a visualization of these results.  As can be seen, the density estimates increase at some specific locations (greener indicates higher b-weight).

Now my question: Is there a formal way to do a similar analysis?

[image]